# How to Replace Multiline texts in multiple files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am not able to replace multi line texts at all  or in other word combining them to one line  . here is the example for the file c:\me\testes.text and the contents are as follows

```
<error.error1>
<error.rec2>
<error.short3>
<error.error4>
<error.rec5>
<error.short6>
```

**My exceptions:**  I want to combine or replace each first 3 lines to one single line across in the multiple files that is

```
<error.error1> <error.rec2> <error.short3>
<error.error4> <error.rec5> <error.short6>
```

I am able to combine each first 2 lines but here its 3 lines .

Please help,
MJ

Comment: please, show your code that you have tried & what did not work as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` to read the file 3 lines at a time by specifying the `-ReadCount` parameter, pipe these 3 lines to `ForEach-Object` and join them together.

```
Get-Content "c:\me\testes.text" -ReadCount 3 | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -join ' '
}
```

Output will look like:

```
<error.error1> <error.rec2> <error.short3>
<error.error4> <error.rec5> <error.short6>
```

To read multiple files, 3 lines at a time you can pipe from `Get-ChildItem` into a loop and then grab the content from the file before joining it back together and writing it back to the respective file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\me\testes\* -Filter *txt | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -ReadCount 3) | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -join ''
    } | Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Not able to test this as not able to save the files, it shows the results in the Pane and does not save. Also i need for multiple files lets say *txt

Comment: somehow i found a alternative method

Comment: #4
$FileName = "c:\me\testes.text"
$pattern = @'
(?ms)error1>
<error
'@

$replace = @'
error1><error
'@

(Get-Content $filename -Raw) -replace $pattern,$replace |
 Set-Content $filename

Comment: For future reference, I have added the solution for loading multiple `.txt` files and then parsing them 3 lines at a time before writing them back to their respective file. The benefit of doing it this way, is if your requirements change in the future, and you find you need to do 4 lines at a time, or 2 lines at time, then you can just update the `-ReadCount` parameter.